# can't run TestNG or JUnit test

Tags: java, testing, junit, cucumber

I worked in project which I implemented a simple feature, stepdefinition class and the runner and want to test it using testJUnit or when I run TestNG.xml.

but I have this problem

```
You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@Given("^sample feature file is ready$")
public void sample_feature_file_is_ready() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("^I run the feature file$")
public void i_run_the_feature_file() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("^run should be successful$")
public void run_should_be_successful() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

my feature is :

```
@smokeTest
Feature: To test my cucumber test is running
I want to run a sample feature file.

Scenario: cucumber setup

Given sample feature file is ready
When I run the feature file
Then run should be successful
```

My stepdefinition is :

```
public class Test_Steps {

      @Given("^sample feature file is ready$")
      public void givenStatment(){
            System.out.println("Given statement executed successfully");
      }

      @When("^I run the feature file$")
      public void whenStatement(){
         System.out.println("When statement execueted successfully");
      }

     @Then("^run should be successful$")
      public void thenStatment(){
         System.out.println("Then statement executed successfully");
      }
```

My runner is :

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
     features = {"D:\\feat\\user"},
     glue={"stepsdef"},
     tags= "@smokeTest")
public class RunnerTestInChrome extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

}
```

How can I know that the stepdefinition class is related to my features! 
I don't understand the problem I implemented the methods scripts

Answer (score 1):

This means that Cucumber cannot find your glue code (step definitions).

**For the glue instead of `glue={"stepsdef"},` provide the path to `stepsdef`.**

Btw, it's recommended to have your feature files in src/test/resources :)

If you can't get it to work, please try the [cucumber-java-skeleton](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton); it's designed to work "out of the box" and should be easier to use than setting up your own project.

If you do want to set up your own project, have a look at this [blogpost](https://medium.com/@mlvandijk/getting-started-with-cucumber-in-java-a-10-minute-tutorial-586652d2c82), which should guide you through the steps of setting up your project and having your files in the right directories...